# CMake add executable with two main files

Tags: c, cmake

I'm not used to CMake, and I want to make an executable with CMake of these files.

`foo.c`

```
#include "foo.h"

void function (){
}

int main(){
}
```

`foo.h`

```
void function();
```

`executable.c`

```
#include "executable.h"

void main(){
    function();
}
```

`executable.h`

```
#include "foo.h"
```

So, now I'm trying to make an executable of `executable.c` using a function inside `foo.c`

This is the `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_executable(EXECUTABLE executable.c)
```

And I get this error.

```
error: redefinition of ‘main’
```

How can I fix this? The problem is that I don't want to make a new `.c` file of `void function()` and include that.

Also, I tried `add_libraries()` but it didn't work in my case. So, if there is something like this,
`something.c`

```
void some_function(){
}
```

and  when `foo.h`

```
#include "something.c"
void function();
```

This didn't work because it said it has multiple definitions of `some_function()`

```
add_libraries(LIB something.c)
add_executables(Executable executable.c LIB)
```

So, is there a way for this?

Comment: You've defined `main` in two different files.  Do you understand how that doesn't make sense?  Define it in one file only.  Either remove it from the other or else don't link with that file.  Take your pick.  Also, you can't declare `main` to be void-valued.  It needs to be declared as int-valued.

Comment: Of course I know have two `main`s and the `void` doesn't make sense. The problem is that I need to use the `function()` which is declared in `foo.c` which also has a main.

Comment: "Of course I know I have two `main`s and the `void` doesn't make sense" - do you understand what he said? It means you have defined two entry points for your program. So if you would manage to compile it to a single program which `main` should it start with? You need to modify one of the files to not include one of the `main` functions. If you can't modify it then you should switch jobs, because management doesn't understand programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a good reason to also have a main function in foo.c, and assuming that when building your executable target, you only want the main function in executable.c to be used, then you can wrap the main function in foo.c with a macro guard like

```c
#ifndef BUILD_MY_EXECUTABLE
int main(){
}
#endif
```

and then in your CMakeLists.txt, use [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) like `target_compile_definitions(EXECUTABLE PRIVATE BUILD_MY_EXECUTABLE)`.

Also, you'd do well to use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your foo.h and executable.h files.

Comment: I think this is right, but will there be another way? Actually I can't use the include guards in the `foo.c`.

Comment: @JakeKim Include guards go in header files- not in implementation files (notice that I said foo.h and executable.h and not foo.c or executable.c?). Sure there are other ways. But this was the simplest one I can think of right now. You can do better than "thinking it's right". You can try it out for yourself.